# Solving for x in flooring functions

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Say you have the equation:

$x\lfloor{\frac{999}{x}}\rfloor = 999$

where x ∈ { 15, 16, 17, ..., 35 }

How would you go about solving for $x$?

Comment: By trying different values for $x$. Then I might try to set $x=999t$ and see where that leads me.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming $x\neq 0$, this directly implies
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{999}{x}\right\rfloor=\frac{999}{x}.
$$

So, the question becomes: for what numbers $w$ is it true that $\lfloor w\rfloor=w$?